# switched to ubuntu from windows but the network is still a windows network

Tags: networking, home-directory

I was dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu on my desktop. I configured a tp-link wr940N router from the windows 7 desktop, and I'd use a windows 7 laptop via wifi.

I just wiped windows and installed ubuntu 12.04 on both the desktop and the laptop. No problem connecting to the internet, whether on the ubuntu desktop or the ubuntu laptop (through wifi) but the network definition is still a 'windows' network, and I'm not able to see one computer from the other. I guess the router is just doing it's thing, as if nothing changed.

What do I need to do to have a regular home network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right click on any folder and select sharing options. You should be able to see the shared folder from the other computer.

BTW you can still change your router configurations from the Ubuntu machine. Open firefox/Chrome, type the router IP address (likely 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.1), type user/password (if prompted for it) and change the config as you please.

Comment: thank you so much; I tried the sharing, which prompted me to install samba, which i did, on both machines. I can see now icon representations of both machines, but I can't actually view any of the contents. the operation just fails. I am so thankful for the router config instructions though. That was precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: I checked this as answered. I'd upvote if I could. Thanks, again.